# How to print results in php using AVG and CHAR_LENGTH in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

How do I show the results for `$wordavg` in php. I have done the query in SQL on database after taking out variables so I believe the query is correct but don't know how to show the results of the search in php.

```
$usertable = 'words';
$yourfield = 'wordname'; 

$query = "SELECT AVG(CHAR_LENGTH( wordname)) AS $wordavg FROM $usertable WHERE $yourfield LIKE '"."$current_letter"."%' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should be using [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead. Back to your question, usually you can iterate over a result with a loop as follows:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['field'];
}
```

More info and examples in the PHP [mysql_query doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Since you only have one row of data to return, you don't need the loop part. You can simply use

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$wordavg = $row['wordavg'];
```

You shouldn't have the `$` in `wordavg` in your query. It should be just `...AS wordavg FROM...`

Comment: $yourfield is a variable representing field wordname tried the while but got error Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ....

Comment: NP but I am getting closer to a solution as every little bit helps

Comment: Thanks got it your answer sent me to the right conclusion to make things work